# Cloud Datastore - Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting the following error while saving data to cloud datastore via nodejs sdk

```
 Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Could not refresh access token.
 at Object.exports.createStatusError
     (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
 at Object.onReceiveStatus
     (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
 at InterceptingListener._callNext
     (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
 at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus
     (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
 at callback
     (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
 code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
     details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Could not refresh access token.'
```

And here the code:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// The kind for the new entity
const kind = 'Task';
// The name/ID for the new entity
const name = 'sampletask1';
// The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);

// Prepares the new entity
const task = {
  key: taskKey,
  data: {
    description: 'Buy milk',
  },
};

// Saves the entity
datastore
  .save(task)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Saved ${task.key.name}: ${task.data.description}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Following version

```
"@google-cloud/datastore": "1.4.1",
```

Comment: Can we assume that that `'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'` is just a place holder for the actual project name?

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from example code which I modified to have the project id.

Comment: Did you give the Cloud Functions Runtime Service Account enough access to Datastore? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#runtime_service_account

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I actually had to re-enable the service to get this role in the service account by default. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#troubleshooting_permission_errors . Also there is an error in the doc , the role is actually cloudfunctions.serviceAgent and its case sensitive.

Comment: @SoulMan Can you post your solution to the problem as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to specific GCO projects which are old and cloud function API was never reset after it went GA.

As per documentation [1] the following role is required for cloud functions to talk to datastore.

> The Cloud Functions service account (service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com) has the cloudfunctions.serviceAgent role on your project.

and

> You can reset this service account to the default role by re-enabling
>   the Cloud Functions API:
>
> ```
> gcloud services enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com
> ```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#troubleshooting_permission_errors